# How do I include the s64 and u64 types used by the linux_dirent64 struct?

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to use the `getdents64` Linux syscall on 64-bit Ubuntu. My code, which is a minimal example based off the `getdents` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getdents.2.html#EXAMPLE), looks like this:

```
    #define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>     /* Defines DT_* constants */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#define handle_error(msg) do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

struct linux_dirent64 {
    u64 d_ino;
    s64 d_off;
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    unsigned char d_type;
    char d_name[0];
};


#define BUF_SIZE 1024

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd, nread;
    char buf[BUF_SIZE];
    struct linux_dirent64 *d;
    int bpos;
    char d_type;

    fd = open(argc > 1 ? argv[1] : ".", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY);
    if (fd == -1)
        handle_error("open");

    for ( ; ; ) {
        nread = syscall(SYS_getdents64, fd, buf, BUF_SIZE);
        if (nread == -1)
            handle_error("getdents64");

        if (nread == 0)
            break;

        printf("--------------- nread=%d ---------------\n", nread);
        printf("inode#    file type  d_reclen  d_off   d_name\n");
        for (bpos = 0; bpos < nread;) {
            d = (struct linux_dirent64 *) (buf + bpos);
            printf("%8d  ", d->d_ino);
            d_type = *(buf + bpos + d->d_reclen - 1);
            printf("%-10s ", (d_type == DT_REG) ?  "regular" :
                             (d_type == DT_DIR) ?  "directory" :
                             (d_type == DT_FIFO) ? "FIFO" :
                             (d_type == DT_SOCK) ? "socket" :
                             (d_type == DT_LNK) ?  "symlink" :
                             (d_type == DT_BLK) ?  "block dev" :
                             (d_type == DT_CHR) ?  "char dev" : "???");
            printf("%4d %10lld  %s\n", d->d_reclen,
                    (long long) d->d_off, d->d_name);
            bpos += d->d_reclen;
        }
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The really important part (where my code breaks) is this:

```
struct linux_dirent64 {
    u64 d_ino; // this is this problem
    s64 d_off; // this too
    unsigned short d_reclen;
    unsigned char d_type;
    char d_name[0];
};
```

When I compile my program I get the following error:

```
hc-24@HP24:~$ gcc v.c 
v.c:14:5: error: unknown type name ‘u64’
     u64 d_ino;
     ^
v.c:15:5: error: unknown type name ‘s64’
     s64 d_off;
     ^
```

I think the problem is that I am including `sys/types.h` to attempt to get `s64` and `u64`. I found an example of someone using `linux_dirent64` online and they just `#include <types.h>`. When I try that, I get the error:

```
hc-24@HP24:~$ gcc v.c 
love.c:8:19: fatal error: types.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

So I somehow have to import these two types (`s64` and `u64`) and I have absolutely no clue. Any suggestions are immensely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your `linux_dirent64` differ from the one in the man page. So perhaps you should try the example from your native `man`?

Comment: "These are not the interfaces you are interested in. Look at
readdir(3) for the POSIX-conforming C library interface. This page
documents the bare kernel system call interfaces." From your linked man page. Maybe you should just use the `readdir` function instead?

Comment: @EugeneSh. That is for getdents, I'm using getdents64 which has a different struct. The man pages only document  linux_dirent, not linux_dirent64, which is different. I got linux_dirent64 from the source code of readdir.

Comment: @JonatanE I absolutely must use `getdents64` unfortunately

Comment: Yeah so using @JonatanE's answer, my code has a ton of other problems. It turns out that getdents and getdents64 are way more different than I thought. I'll work on it and edit my question. But it looks like the specific problem I was having is solved(ish). Thanks everyone!

Comment: Okay, edited source code so that the issues (unrelated to the question) are fixed. So now, combining the question's code with @JonatanE answer code will work. yay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that `<types.h>` is a header in the linux kernel source.

See [this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/types.h) link for the source.

Here is an excerpt from that file:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
typedef u64         uint64_t;
typedef u64         u_int64_t;
typedef s64         int64_t;
#endif
```

So, I guess you could just add this to your code in order to get it to compile.

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef u64 uint64_t;
typedef s64 int64_t;
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a *proper* solution.

Comment: That did the trick. Turns out I'm also using getdents64 a bit incorrectly, though, so I'll fix the code in my question for people in the future (plus me since I need it to work, haha)