# What is the header for the struct linux_dirent64?

Tags: c, linux

I'm exploring the `getdents64` syscall. The resulting `struct linux_dirent64` is not defined by the relevant headers. Both the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54241059/10477326) and the example in [`man 2 getdirents64`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/docs/man-pages/man-pages.git/tree/man2/getdents.2?h=man-pages-6.01#n263) are declaring their own structs. Although I'm aware of Linux syscall backwards compatibility, defining the struct locally like that looks like a hack. Is there another header I need to include that has this `struct linux_dirent64` defined inside?

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct linux_dirent64 {
  ino64_t d_ino;
  off64_t d_off;
  unsigned short d_reclen;
  unsigned char d_type;
  char d_name[];
};

void test() {
  char buf[1024];
  const int procfs = open("/proc", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY | O_CLOEXEC);
  getdents64(procfs, buf, 1024);
  printf("%lu\n", ((struct linux_dirent64 *) buf)->d_ino);
  close(procfs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `struct linux_dirent64` to just [`struct dirent64`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/dirent.h;h=b760f6860e3f2121578b326d4174280f9ad6b4d3;hb=c804cd1c00adde061ca51711f63068c103e94eef#l37). This works with glibc 2.36. It is not necessary to include another header as `#include <dirent.h>` provides it with `#define _GNU_SOURCE`. The original code would look like the following:

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void test() {
  char buf[1024];
  const int procfs = open("/proc", O_RDONLY | O_DIRECTORY | O_CLOEXEC);
  getdents64(procfs, buf, 1024);
  printf("%lu\n", ((struct dirent64 *) buf)->d_ino);
  close(procfs);
}
```